# $cordovaSQLite not working on AVD or Android device

Tags: android, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

**Methods like : $cordovaSQLite.openDB(), $cordovaSQLite.execute() not working.**
Below is my Enviornment of POC:

**java** version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)

**Apache Ant**(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014

**node** --version
v0.10.25

**cordova** -version
4.3.1

**ionic** -version
1.7.12

Following is error in console if i run command: ionic run android -l -c

error    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined, http://192.168.2.10:8100/js/ng-cordova.min.js, Line: 9

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: @Beat I have added the error form console in Question